# How to excluder a folder from search and indexing (JetBrains IDEs)?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

The question is about Rider, but I hope this setting is similar for all Jet Brain's Ides.

I have several folders with `js` and `css` bundles. For example the folders are situated in `wwwroot/buildjs` and `wwwroot/buildcss`.

The problem is when I press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd> to find something in the solution or (that is worse) when I try to rename something with the help of refactoring instruments (Right click -> Refactor -> Rename) Rider tries to rename in the bundles too! It's very slow, and I don't need it! Could somebody tell me ho to exclude this folders?

I remember early I could do it with the help of Right click on the folder -> Tools (not sure but maybe) -> Exclude from index. But now I don't see this  menu item.

Comment: **Cannot say about Rider (not using it)** but in other IDEA-based IDEs that would normally be `Mark Folder As... | Excluded` via context menu in Project View panel (or via `Settings/Preferences | Directories` .. which will be different for each IDE -- that one is for PhpStorm/WebStorm that have more simple project structure; in IntelliJ IDEA it will have another item in the settings path -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#folder-categories).

Comment: Are these folders included in .net project?

Comment: @xtmq yes I suppose. When I remove one of these folder I see changes in git. The changes are about `.csproj` file. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Probably you see `exclude` changes in the project file? For now Rider indexes all files which are part of msbuild project

Comment: Anyway I suggest you to wait a bit. In 1 or 2 weeks we publish a new Rider 2021.1 EAP 3 build, you can try. I have rewritten files indexing there completely. Probably it would fix your case

Comment: @xtmq I have installed rider 2021 beta. And there is no exclude file from index feature(

Comment: Are you trying to exclude something which is belong to .NET project?

Comment: @xtmq I'm trying to exclude a big folder with JavaScript and CSS bundles that is situated in `wwwroot`. Is it possible?

Comment: Is this folder included in an msbuild project? in csproj file? If yes, no it is not possible for now, feel free to track this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-24072

Answer (score 18):

The workaround that solved it for me was to:

- right click the folder > Tools > Stop Index

This will not index the folder and so it won't appear on search results.
I did this for each folder I have on the project.

I think this is an open bug: [`https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-2173`](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-2173)

Comment: worked in 2022.2

Comment: it seems that you also need to click _File -> Invalidate Caches_ after that for change to take effect